# after install ns2: syntax error near unexpected token 'You'

Tags: linux, syntax-error, ubuntu-16.04, simulation, ns2

after install ns2 i meet this problem 
IMPORTANT: command not found
bash: /home/tuanhoang/.bashrc: line 144: syntax error near unexpected token `You'
bash: /home/tuanhoang/.bashrc: line 144:`(1) You MUST put /home/tuanhoang/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14, /home/tuanhoang/ns-allinone-2.35/lib, 
syntax error near unexpected token 'You'

I am using ubuntu 16.04. How can i solve this problem ? Thank all of you guys for your responds

Comment: Maybe this question should be migrated to [Super User](https://superuser.com)...

Comment: You are not supposed to follow that ancient text https://askubuntu.com/questions/970439/cant-install-ns2-in-ubuntu-with-the-below-error-as-shown-in-picture ... Restore .bashrc to its default : `/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/` https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/how-do-i-restore-bashrc-to-its-default . ... About ns2 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g33hBASBF49Fqf5XbfmSHe1-mLTU2yjH/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some program has put a comment in your `~/.bashrc` file without properly prefixing each line with `#`.

Read the comment in the file and follow its instruction.  Then either remove it or comment it out properly by prefixing it with `#`.